# SendGrid: 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: api, sendgrid

I am trying to set up the web api for SendGrid.

I can't create the environment variable. In CMD or Anaconda Prompt, when I enter `source ./sendgrid.env`

I get:
**'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

++++++++
Instructions from SendGrid +++++++++++++++++++

**Create an environment variable
Update your development environment with your SENDGRID_API_KEY. Run the following in your shell:**

```
echo "export SENDGRID_API_KEY='XXXXX'" > sendgrid.env
echo "sendgrid.env" >> .gitignore
source ./sendgrid.env
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C+operable+program+or+batch+file

Comment: Windows command does not use `source` to set environmental variables. Use `SET` or do it via the Settings menu (search for "Environment variables").

Comment: @Ken White
SET ./sendgrid.env

Comment: I get error: "Environment variable ./sendgrid.env not defined"

Comment: You're mixing *nix and Windows. As I said, use `SET` or the Windows settings dialog. I'd suggest that you learn to use your operating system before you try to program. `./` is not Windows syntax. The syntax for setting an environmental variable is `SET variablename=variablecontent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` is a *nix command and it appears you are using Windows.

Windows also doesn't support `export` to set environment variables. To set an environment variable you can either [use the UI, as described in this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html). Or you can use the [`set` function](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-command-line-and-registry/), e.g.

```
set SENDGRID_API_KEY SG.xxx
```

Then you should be able to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

## I am using a Windows system and facing same issue:

- I have created a .env file in project root directory and paste below:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'
```

Note: Replace "YOUR_API_KEY" with your actual API key.

- Install dotenv library using pip:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

- Import and load environment variables from .env file:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()
```

- retrieve your key in python code:

```
sendgrid_api_key = os.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
```